# How to backup/restore a large MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, database-backup

How can I backup and restore a large mongodb database (500GB) from a server running an older version (v2.6) than the target one (v3.6)?. The downtime is critical.

We've tried by making a straight copy of the data files as well as filesystem snapshot, but these two methods result in incompatibility issues.

Comment: "Large" and "too long" are too general terms that practically say nothing. You need to be more specific.

Comment: Did you try filesystem snapshots? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/

Comment: Also this might be useful in creating incremental backups. https://github.com/Dabz/mongo-backup